# One vendor prefix inside a different vendor prefix

Tags: css, media-queries, vendor-prefix

I've recently came across a project with css rules like this:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
    #header .searchform input:-moz-placeholder, #header .searchform textarea:-moz-placeholder {
        line-height: 140%;
    }
}
```

In my opinion this is kinda weird, as I know vendor prefixes are used to target different browsers. What about a situation like this then, when you use a different vendor prefix compared to the parent? Is it just a typo from a previous programmer? Or is it a perfectly valid rule that would apply in certain scenarios? If yes, what would the scenario be when this rule gets applied?

Comment: `-webkit-` is going to target a different browser engine than `input: moz-placeholder`...

Comment: Looks like a mistake to me, unless `(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)` evaluates as true for non-webkit scenarios too and then works as a passthru for other vendors. Which, of course, seems possibly non-documenting and confusing (no one *ever* writes code like *that*).

Comment: @ShaunLoftin, that is precisely my concern. So I'm right to delete these rules altogether as there is no chance they would get applied?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, that sentence `unless (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) evaluates as true for non-webkit scenarios too and then works as a passthru for other vendors` is what worries me the most as I'm no css guru, so there might be something I'm missing and that's why I wanted to ask people here :)

Comment: I don't know either (my *media-query-foo* is very foo-bar). I would have interpreted it as a mistake, ripped it out, and the universe would have collapsed on itself (three months later, at the worst possible moment, *since there is a worst-possible-moment* for the universe to collapse, naturally). I suppose you can look for elements that fit that designation and inspect them in other browsers to see if it's applied?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, can't see it applied anywhere, but maybe there's some specific scenario, which this code tries to fix. Not sure.. I think I'm going just delete it and rely on git, so I can rollback the changes if some customer starts to complain. I'll leave the question active if someone has a different experience with this.

Comment: Goodbye sweet universe. We hardly knew ye. `:P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a careless mistake. There are no known implementations of Gecko that recognize `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` — the prefix that Gecko uses is [`min--moz-device-pixel-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#-moz-device-pixel-ratio)<sup>1</sup> instead, which has since been deprecated in favor of the standardized `resolution`. And there are no known implementations of WebKit or Blink that recognize `:-moz-placeholder`.

Either way, this snippet of CSS is meaningless to both engines. At best, in WebKit/Blink, you get an empty `@media screen and (...) {}` rule, and in Gecko, [you theoretically get `@media not all { ... }`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#error-handling), which means "this rule will never be applied in any situation".

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Unlike the code in the question, this is not a typo.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0` Is a browser hack to target Safari 3+ and Chrome 1+.

`input:-moz-placeholder` Is a pseudo-class that has been deprecated in Firefox 19 in favor of the ::-moz-placeholder pseudo-element and only targets Firefox browsers.

Given your code that your code is asking to target Safari and Chrome only to then run code for FireFox only; it's ultimately code that will never run under any circumstances and is likely a mistake.

Additional information can be read on the Safari 3+ / Chrome 1+ hack here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

and more information on -moz-placeholder can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-placeholder

and more information on style placeholder text in general can be found here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/